# Is there a way to restart (Stop and Start) AWS ElasticSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

Not sure why AWS ES does not allow the cluster to be stopped and started. I believe behind the scene its just a set of AWS EC2 instances that themselves could be easily stopped and started. This way customers may not have to take backup delete cluster, launch new restore from back up and then not to mention work with the new URL!! I understand that the service provider(AWS) needs to maintain/reserve the instances for customers while they are not "in the job".

Therefore,

1. Is there a way to restart (stop and start) AWS ES?
2. If not, aside from this possible financial non-viability is there any other key technical reasons I am missing that allows this kind of architecture to be the most appropriate?
   BTW, I looked at elastic.co and they have same concept (Except they call it "shutdown").

Thanks,
Rahul